# Accurately place text over image with background-size cover

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

Sorry if this is hard to understand but it's also tricky to explain.

I have a div with this CSS:

```
    .gallery{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
            background-image:url(image.jpg);
            background-size:cover;
    }
```

... so the image always covers the viewport at all sizes.

I'd like to layer some text over this that keeps the same relative position with respect to the image (just relative position, the size stays the same, its just a few words)

I can put the image in a div then use a percentage top padding to mimic the aspect ratio of the image. BUT once the image starts to get cropped (as its using background-cover) the aspect ratio is no longer the same as the original image, so after a while the text starts to cover parts of the images that it shouldn't.

One solution seems to be to use aspect ratio media queries and just adjust the percentage as the aspect changes but it's fiddly and doesn't feel right.

Any ideas or is this just not possible? I know the dimensions of the image so perhaps I can use that info to simulate background-cover on the text div?

Answer (score 0):

One answer may be to use SVG for your text.
If I understand your question correctly you want the text to scale with the image (which is really just a div with an image background).

Normal HTML text won't scale. However SVG text will.

```
<text style="font-weight: bold;">This is text in Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG)</text>
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thanks for this - my question was a little misleading actually as I don't want the text to scale, I just want the relative position to stay the same - I've edited my question to make it clearer. Interesting idea though. I could create a div the same dimensions as the image, then set the text as a background SVG image and use background-size cover too. I'd prefer to keep with actual text though.

Comment: Just tried using an SVG image at the same dimensions as the image below with its background set to cover. It stays in the correct position but like the background image below the it gets cropped as certain aspect ratios. I think there must be a JS solution but can't find anything easy enough to follow